# How to turn off page bounce-back in Mobile IE (Windows Phone 7/Mango)

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-7

I'm developing a web app which is full screen within the browser on Mobile IE.

Is there a way to turn off the rubber-band effect bounce back at the top and bottom of the page? It's really annoying as it kicks in when you reach the bottom of a scrollable div and moves the whole page out of view.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ever find a solution for this? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: No, doesn't seem to be possible.